# Error in deploy Gunicorn and Supervisor on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm new to this, so please be patient

I am trying to deploy a flask app using AWS Ubuntu machine with open ports 
 **443** and **80**

when I run the flask app using `sudo python app.py` it works.

The problem appears when I try to use `gunicorn`. when I use the command

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:443 app:app
```

it pushes this error

```
[2018-06-18 13:30:30 +0000] [11135] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.8.1
[2018-06-18 13:30:30 +0000] [11135] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-06-18 13:30:31 +0000] [11135] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-06-18 13:30:32 +0000] [11135] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-06-18 13:30:33 +0000] [11135] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-06-18 13:30:34 +0000] [11135] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2018-06-18 13:30:35 +0000] [11135] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 443)
```

I have checked that no process listen to port **443** using `lsof -i:443`

Here is app.py

```
from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='443')
```

**Edited**  : gunicorn error solved by installing it using `sudo -H pip install gunicorn`

I am trying to deploy app in production so i want it continuously running . i tried `supervisor` to keep it up all the time

Here is the configuration of `supervisor`

```
[program:app_name]
directory=/home/ubuntu/FIFA_Captcha
command=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:443 app:app
autostart=true
user=root
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/app_name.err.log
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/app_name.out.log
environment=PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python
```

output `sudo service supervisor status`

```
Jun 18 22:02:39 ip-172-31-3-59 systemd[1]: Started Supervisor process control system for UNIX.
Jun 18 22:02:39 ip-172-31-3-59 supervisord[19562]: 2018-06-18 22:02:39,828 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
Jun 18 22:02:39 ip-172-31-3-59 supervisord[19562]: 2018-06-18 22:02:39,829 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/app_name.conf" Jun 18 22:02:39 ip-172-31-3-59 supervisord[19562]: 2018-06-18 22:02:39,834 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
Jun 18 22:02:39 ip-172-31-3-59 supervisord[19562]: 2018-06-18 22:02:39,834 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authenticatJun 18 22:02:39 ip-172-31-3-59 supervisord[19562]: 2018-06-18 22:02:39,834 INFO supervisord started with pid 19562
Jun 18 22:02:40 ip-172-31-3-59 supervisord[19562]: 2018-06-18 22:02:40,837 INFO spawned: 'app_name' with pid 19569
Jun 18 22:02:40 ip-172-31-3-59 supervisord[19562]: 2018-06-18 22:02:40,952 INFO exited: app_name(exit status 3; not expected)
Jun 18 22:02:41 ip-172-31-3-59 supervisord[19562]: 2018-06-18 22:02:41,955 INFO spawned: 'app_name' with pid 19574
Jun 18 22:02:42 ip-172-31-3-59 supervisord[19562]: 2018-06-18 22:02:42,069 INFO exited: app_name(exit status 3; not expected)
```

output from `app_name.err.log`. Although I set `PYTHONPATH`

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/FIFA_Captcha/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
ImportError: No module named flask
[2018-06-18 22:09:34 +0000] [19681] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19681)
[2018-06-18 22:09:34 +0000] [19677] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-06-18 22:09:34 +0000] [19677] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Comment: Can you share your gunicorn config file? Also, what user are you running gunicorn as? You'd need to be root to use port 443.

Comment: I use the default configuration. I am using ubuntu user, when adding `sudo` to the command `sudo gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:443 app:app` getting the same error

Comment: I was able to recreate the problem on my system but using sudo solved it.  Something is either using 443 already or you do not have permissions to use that port.  Maybe try another one (over 2000) and see what happens?  You can always put an ELB infront of the machine to send SSL traffic to that port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to be root to use port 443.

Comment: I managed to solve the gunicorn error but I faced a problem when I added it to `supervisor`. i edited the question

Comment: Try setting `user=root`

Comment: Ah.  It looks like your python packages are not installed system wide.  This is necessary for running using your setup (more or less).  Run `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt` if you have created a requirements file, otherwise you'll have to install them manually.  Do not use a virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks . It works after install python libraries system wide